# CSRF tokens out of sync in Chrome v27.0.1453.93 in OS X 10.6.8

Tags: php, csrf

To lock form submissions to my domain (in this case, localhost), I am using a synchronizer cookie in the following general way:

```
<?php setcookie('csrf_token',$randomizedToken,0,'','/'); ?>
```

In the web form, I inject the token into a hidden field:

```
<input name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $randomizedToken; ?>" />
```

Now, when I load the above in Chrome and use Developer Tools to examine the source/cookies/etc, I find that the cookie value and the hidden form value do not match until I refresh (command+R) WHILE in Developer Tools. Predictably, when I attempt to submit the form, the cookie and POSTed token do not match, and the form is not processed. Note that among the browsers I've tested (Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox & Camino for OS X, Mobile Safari and Mobile Chrome for iOS), this problem is only occurring in Chrome for OS X. In all other browsers, the cookie and hidden form value are synchronized and submission works as expected.

After banging my head against the wall for a few hours, I tried commenting out my .htaccess rewrite directive which forwards all non-file and non-directory requests to /index.php. After doing so, the cookie and token values began syncing up in Chrome and form submission worked as expected. The .htaccess directive is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Some quick googling informed me that unless redirect behavior is specified in the rewrite rule, apache should be simply fetching the aliased request in the background without issuing a redirect to the browser. Yet, Chrome seems to be receiving a redirect which is causing the token values to become unsynced. I'm at a total loss here since I need to protect the forms from CSRF attacks, but also need to have rewriting enabled in order to map to application resources. Obviously I can't just ignore OS X Chrome users.

Has anybody encountered a similar problem, and how did you resolve it?

**UPDATE**

After posting this question, I had the idea of moving the .htaccess file from the root web directory into the /resource directory and form submission in that directory is now fine. This means that I will have to include a separate (but identical) .htaccess into each directory requiring URL rewrites instead of having one .htaccess at the root of the website. This is workable but a bit of a pain, so if anybody has a more elegant solution, I'd love to hear it!